# How to abort a already-started swing worker thread?

Tags: java, swing

If I have started a SwingWorker thread by invoking its execute(). Is there any way that I can interrupt it at its execution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you control the code of the SwingWorker, you can poll [`isCancelled()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html#isCancelled%28%29) at appropriate places in [`doInBackground()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html#doInBackground%28%29), and then stop doing work if it returns `true`. Then [cancel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html#cancel(boolean)) the worker when you feel like it:

```
class YourWorker extends SwingWorker<Foo, Bar> {

    // ...

    protected Foo doInBackground() throws Exception {
        while (someCondition) {
            publish(doSomeIntermediateWork());
            if (isCancelled())
                return null; // we're cancelled, abort work
        }
        return calculateFinalResult();
    }

}

// To abort the task:
YourWorker worker = new YourWorker(args);
worker.execute();
doSomeOtherStuff();
if (weWantToCancel)
    worker.cancel(false); // or true, doesn't matter to us here
```

Now, as you noted, `cancel(boolean)` can fail, but why? The [Javadocs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html#cancel%28boolean%29) inform us:

> #### Returns:
>
> `false` if the task could not be cancelled, typically because it has already completed normally; `true` otherwise.